# using AzureFileCopy task outputs in Azure-Pipelines.yml

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I am trying to output `outputStorageUri` and `outputStorageContainerSasToken` from the AzureFileCopy task and consume them in a powershell script, a simple example of what I am trying to achieve is:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'VS2017-Win2016'

variables:
  Parameters.outputStorageUri: ''
  Parameters.outputStorageContainerSasToken: ''

steps:

- task: AzureFileCopy@3
  inputs:
    sourcePath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\MyProgram.ext'
    azureSubscription: 'MyAzureServiceRole'
    Destination: 'AzureBlob'
    storage: 'myfilestorage'
    ContainerName: 'programs'
    outputStorageUri: '$(Parameters.outputStorageUri)'
    outputStorageContainerSasToken: '$(Parameters.outputStorageContainerSasToken)'
    sasTokenTimeOutInMinutes: 5
  displayName: Upload program to Blob storage


- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: |
          Write-Host 'URL = ' + $Env:PARAMETERS_OUTPUTSTORAGEURI
      errorActionPreference: 'stop'
      failOnStderr: 'false'
  displayName: Send storage URL to Logger(s)
```

The file is copied correctly, however Write-Host in the example for the outputStorageUri is always blank! I have also tried a number of other ways to no avail... Please can someone enlighten me as to what I am doing wrong...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We should use the **name** of the variable, not the variable value in the task.

Please change the `$(Parameters.outputStorageUri)` to `Parameters.outputStorageUri`
`$(Parameters.outputStorageContainerSasToken)` to `Parameters.outputStorageContainerSasToken`, then it will work.

```
outputStorageUri: Parameters.outputStorageUri
outputStorageContainerSasToken: Parameters.outputStorageContainerSasToken
```

[image]

For more information please refer to [Azure File Copy](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureFileCopyV1/README.md#parameters-of-the-task)

> provide the **name** of the output variable you would like to use.

Answer (score 3):

Kind of related but if you are using V4 then these are available as Output Variables.
This is not there in the documentation but highlighted in this issue.

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/13246